# Blogger google api get userid

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, blogger, google-api-php-client

When authenticating the user how can I get the userID in order for me to list their blogs.

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_BloggerService.php'; 
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Blogger');
$client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_simple_api_key');
$blogger = new Google_BloggerService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    var_dump($blogger->blogs->listByUser("USER_ID_HERE")); //how do i get the user id?
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

The documentation is useless all it shows is how to get blogs posts etc using unknowns i.e blogID,  postID etc. to be able to get blogID, postID I need the initial userID which is not given when authenticating.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

Comment: sorry that's in a common file should have mentioned my bad!!

Comment: listByUser function receive $userId `@param string $userId ID of the user whose blogs are to be fetched. Either the word 'self' (sans quote marks) or the user's profile identifier.`

Answer (score 2):

While doing blogger OAuth, I also come across same problem. But after reading 5-10 times the documentation it comes to me that we don't need the userID for getting the blogID. After getting the Access Token you can retrieve a list of a user's blogs by sending an HTTP GET request to the blogs collection URI:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/{userId}/blogs
```

or the request as:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
```

**Note:** The user must be authenticated to list their own blogs, so you must provide the Authorization HTTP header with the GET request.

For more information visit [google bloger api docs](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0)

Comment: Could you please include how it can be done with PHP, I have tried everything

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump($blogger->blogs->listByUser('self'));`

Comment: please explain your answer a bit more

Comment: There is no method to get userID to put it instead of "USER_ID_HERE". But we can get list of blogs by user from the user's access token.